# Shared data between threads not right

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a problem with a program of mine. The sum data is shared between multiple Threads. Its supposed to give the sum after each Thread adds onto that.

```
public class ThreadPractise implements Runnable
{
    Integer num;
    String name;
    volatile Integer commonSum;
    Object lock;

    public ThreadPractise(Integer i,String threadName ,Integer sum, Object sharedLock) {
        num = i;
        name = threadName;
        commonSum =sum;
        lock = sharedLock;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Integer cube = calculate(num);
        update(cube);
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" has commonSum after update as "+commonSum);
    }

    public void update(Integer cube) {
        synchronized (lock) {
            this.commonSum = this.commonSum + cube;
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" has commonSum as "+commonSum);
        }
    }
    public int calculate(Integer num2) {
        return (num2*num2*num2);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Integer sum = new Integer(0);
        Object lock = new Object();
        for(int i=1;i<=3;i++)
        {
            Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadPractise(i, "Thread"+i, sum,lock));
            t.start();
            try {
                t.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Sum of 1^3+2^3+3^3 = "+sum);

    }

}
```

However the sum is always 0. When i am changing to AtomicInteger its working but i need the problem with this implementation. Also please tell me if the Thread locking i am doing is right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is not related to concurrency. Look at your `main` method. It has a local variable `sum`. This local variable is never updated. Instead, you are changing the object that the `num` field of your `ThreadPractise` instance references. This value is initialized with the value of `sum` but once you are replacing the value of `num`, its value is not longer related to `sum` as the value is simply replaced but not updated. Thus, the value that is printed remains `0` which is the value that is originally assigned to `sum`.

What you do is simply put:

```
Integer a = 0;
Integer b = a;
b = 1;                 // does not change a
System.out.println(a); // prints '0'
```

But in Java, you cannot change the value that is referenced by a variable without assigning a new value to this variable.

In contrast, with `AtomicInteger` you are passing a **mutable** instance to your thread. Instead of replacing the value that is referenced by `num`, you are now updating the value that this very same instance represents. This way, the `num` and the `sum` variables remain identical as they reference an identical object. This approach is not possible with an `Integer` which is **immutable**. If the `Integer` class had a method like `setValue(int)` what you are doing would work as `sum` and `num` would similarly reference the same object.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just to add onto the question. I am relatively new to Threading. Is the locking that i am doing in the program right.

Comment: Also just a doubt with the answer. I am using the new keyword once only in main. Then on what version of the variables are the Threads executing..

Comment: In general, you should only lock on `final` fields in order to assure that you are always locking on the same instance. Other than that, your code looks correct. However, using an `AtomicInteger` would be the better way of approaching concurrency as it is *lock free* and thus runs more performant.

Answer (score 2):

`Integer` is immutable. You cannot pass an `Integer` into a method and expect to get an updated version that way.

If you don't want to use `AtomicInteger` (which is updatable and even in a thread-safe fashion, that would be my preferred solution), you need to retrieve the partial sums from each of your threads or have the threads update a common accumulator somewhere (for example by making `commonSum` static).

Answer (score 2):

`Integer` objects are immutable. While the `Integer` instance that exists in your `Thread` is initially the same as the one that you've declared in your main method, it's replaced with a new instance every time its value changes, i.e. every time you add to `commonSum`. All your threads will hold a reference to a different `Integer` object, and the instance in your main method will be unaffected.

You would have to wrap your `Integer` into some kind of object to be able to share it between your main method and your threads. `AtomicInteger` does just that, and, as an added bonus, will do all the synchronization for you.

Comment: Thanks i get it. This is the answer to one of the comments i asked before.